# If browser IE8, open custom HTML page via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to browser detection and control.
Tried this way and it works:

```
  <!--[if IE 8]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('hey');
  </script>
  <![endif]-->
```

But I want, if the site open on IE8, getting custom.html page.

How can I do it?

Comment: `window.location.replace('newURL')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. With HTACCESS (And this is what **I** would do):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [8]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain/custom.html [R=301,L]
```

Option 2. With JavaScript:

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   window.location.replace('link to custom.html goes here')
   </script>
<![endif]-->
```